# How did the Stargates get to the planets?

Tags: stargate

Somebody put them there so they can travel quickly between planets, but how did they travel to the planet far away without a Stargate to build one there?

Answer (score 31):

[Stargate Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Universe) takes place on the [starship Destiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_starships_in_Stargate#Destiny), a huge ship of The Ancients whose purpose is to explore the universe without Stargates.  The Destiny is capable of FTL and uses stellar plasma as fuel.  Destiny was preceded by [Seed Ships](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Seed_ship) which would scout ahead and manufacture and plant Stargates.

Whether this is how the rest of the Stargates were seeded, via automated starship, is unknown.  But it was likely using FTL drive to initially reach a planet and building a Stargate upon arrival.

Answer (score 28):

The Ancients placed all of the gates in both the Pegasus as well as milky way galaxies. They also had the ability to travel faster than light in large ships that could carry multiple star gates at a time to drop them off on planets that could potentially have life. 
The Ancient's home galaxy was the galaxy the Ori remained in, and they most likely had already created the gate network in that galaxy before heading to the milky way.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, the builders of the stargates had starships that let them travel to all those planets and install the gates. The same way the Goauld have starships. You see one Goauld ship in the movie, and you see a lot of their ships in the series.

Comment: I was gonna +1 but it just sounds so condescending.

Comment: Actually, "obviously" is not a reason or justification (and the Goa'uld ships are completely irrelevant), so -1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

The Ancients seeded planets with stargates using superluminal ships. One of these ships is the setting for the series [Stargate: Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Universe).

Comment: i don't believe they claim to have used a destiny type ship in the Pegasus or milky way galaxies, they seem to have been far more active in the placement of those gates. Destiny was a 1 of a kind ship sent into reaches of universe the ancients had not yet explored.

Comment: @Himarm it wasn't Destiny but rather the [seed ship](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Seed_ship) that [built](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/File:Gate_Manufacturing.png) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFd1KIQye4Q)) and deployed the gates. Destiny was a follow up ship to the seed ship.

Comment: @MichaelT thanks hadn't seen this episode(universe was so awful i couldn't watch season 2), however, these seed ships were still created to seed far away galaxies not the milky way/pegasus galaxies that already contained gates.

Comment: Sure the Destiny seed ship probably wasn't used.  But I don't see why they couldn't have done something similar for seeding the Milky Way, and Pegasus.

Comment: @Zoredache: I think the main reason they might not have done it that way is because in a single galaxy you can do it with manned ships and choose exactly where you want the gates. The reason the seed ships were unmanned is because of the scope of their mission that a live crew is impractical. Its all just opinion though really. What makes more sense to me isn't necessarily what makes more sense to others.

Comment: My opinion was SG:U was just starting to get interesting when they cancelled the show.  Also IMO they spent too much time trying to build angsty personality conflicts and not enough time actually exploring and solving problems.

The only real personality development I really wanted to follow was the Dr.'s real objectives.  He clearly had some hidden goals and we never discovered them.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you need to remember is that even before the Destiny the Ancients (shown in Stargate Ark of Truth) used a giant spaceship to evade the Ori armies and flee to the Milky Way galaxy.

The had the capacity to seed worlds and merely (as mentioned in season 1 of SG-1) used the Stargate for convenience, not as a requirement for travel.

So the real question is not *how* without ships but *which* ship, the Destiny or some other ship; as others have stated this has never been made clear.

In contrary to @Himarm's answer: it is hard to say if the Ancients created the gates in the Ori galaxy. Hints in SG-1 (Ancient story book) and Ark of Truth suggest that it was still in the idea phase when the ancients left, but that is also not clear.

Comment: _"merely (as mentioned in season 1 of SG-1) used the Stargate for convenience, not as a requirement for travel"_ In which episode was that mentioned?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It would take re-watching to say that, I don't have a photographic memory. I wrote that answer shortly after re-watching season 10 and the finale movie so it was still fresh

Comment: Well the reason I ask is that I have no recollection of it and doubt its veracity. The SGC hadn't even heard of the Ancients in season one, let alone made any determination as to how they got around the galaxy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit tbh it may have been after they visited that world with the first SG guy on it where they learn about the first 4 races. Can't remember which season it is. I believe it was before "The 5th race"

Comment: You are referring to the first season episode "The Torment of Tantalus".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, I am pretty sure I remember it hearing it somewhere near that episode

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe I should change it to season 8? I am fairly certain Daniel makes a reference to it when O'Neill gets his head "sucked" again by a "dang head sucker".

Comment: I think you should try to find an actual transcript quote rather than wildly guessing ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit meh, when I get a chance

Answer (score 1):

We see in *The Ark of Truth* that the Ancients had large starships at the time that Amelius had the idea that would become the Stargates. Therefore it's entirely reasonable to suppose that the Stargates made it to their planets via starship.

Furthermore (although this proves nothing about the Milky Way, Pegasus, Ida, or Ori-galaxy networks) we see evidence of this in SGU in the form of the seed ships, whose purpose included constructing and delivering gates to planets.